# Flask_WTF / Python: init value turns to None if HTML POST is performed

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am working on a quick project to train my Python/Flask/Flask_WTF skills.
Unfortunately, I have spent 2 days without understanding the behavior of my code and the different values.

Here is the simplified code (all modules loaded) for a better visibility for you.

- Note: MovieDB is a class inherited from db.model (SQLAlchemy) with different keys (no issue here)

[MAIN.PY]

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    ##### Test init of DB to check above is correct
    if not Path("instance/movies.db").exists():
        print("OK")
        db_test_init()
    ##### End of test init
    return render_template("index.html", DB=MovieDB.query.filter_by().all())
```

The issue comes in the route below.

```
@app.route("/edit", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def edit():
    movie_id = request.args.get("id")
    movie_edit = MovieDB.query.get(movie_id)

    print(movie_id, movie_edit)

    form_edit = EditForm()  # creating a form object (here 2 fields and a submit button)
    if form_edit.validate_on_submit():  # if button is pushed

        print(movie_id, MovieDB.query.get(movie_id))

        # movie_to_edit.rating = form_edit.rating.data
        # movie_to_edit.review = form_edit.review.data
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for("home"))
    return render_template("edit.html", movie=movie_edit, form=form_edit)
```

[EDIT.HTML]

```
{% block content %}
<div class="content">
    <h1 class="heading">{{ movie.title }}</h1>
    <p class="description">Edit Movie Rating</p>
    <form action="{{ url_for('edit') }}" method="POST">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ render_form(form, button_style='btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg') }}
        <input type='hidden' name="id" value="{{ movie.id }}" />
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Now what happens in the "edit" route:

- if I use a GET

> first print returns: 1 <MovieDB 1>     ==> OK

- if I use a POST (upon submit button in the form)

> first print now returns: None None
> second print returns: None None

How come the first print gets a different value even before getting into the statement
`if form_edit.validate_on_submit():`

Answer (score 0):

`request.args` contains optional query parameters appended to the URL after a question mark. Typically used for GET requests, such as search queries.

```
http://localhost:5000/edit?arg0=0&arg1=1
```

If you enter a URL in the action attribute of the form using `url_for` without setting the `id` attribute, this will not be included in `request.args`. For this reason, `None` is returned for both values.
Pass the `id` to `url_for` and this will be appended to the url.

```
url_for('edit', id=movie.id)
```

With [variable rules](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) there is a possibility to assume the `id` within the URL.

```
@app.route('/edit/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit(id):
    # your code here
```

As described above, you can assign the `movie.id` to the attribute `id` within `url_for` and this will be integrated into the path of the URL.
In my opinion, the most sensible way to transmit the `id` to the server for this purpose.

`request.form` contains the form data and can be used in the same way as `request.args`. However, the hidden input field is ignored by you within the endpoint. But it is another possible option to transfer the data.

There are also other attributes of the `request` object that can be used for other purposes, such as transferring files or receiving data in JSON format.

Comment: Many thanks @Detlef for taking time to guide me.

The issue was right into this statement: 
`url_for('edit', id=movie.id)`

I thought the `request.args.get("id")` would work by default as looking up for the tag `name="id"` ... but was indeed actually looking up to the one above.

I did not need to pass the variable in the `@app.route` in the end.

Happy new year to you !